# Elastic search exact match search on attachment type content

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to perform an exact search match in the content of indexed files (pdfs) that have been correctly indexed into ES using the attachment plugin.

I already know that to perform an exact match search I have to specify `"index" : "not_analyzed"` in the mapping of the specific field.

I tried to to the same with the attachment type but it seems it is not working as expected.
I tested the following two mappings:

```
{
    doc: {
        "properties": {
            file : { 
                "type" : "attachment",
                "index" : "not_analyzed",
                "fields" : {
                    "title" : { "store" : "yes" },
                    "file" : { "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets", "store":"yes" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

{
    doc: {
        "properties": {
            file : { 
                "type" : "attachment",
                "fields" : {
                    "title" : { "store" : "yes" },
                    "file" : { "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets", "store":"yes", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But they didn't help me to achieve the exact search match I wanted.

Could you please provide me some help on this? 
Do you know if the attachment plugin supports the exact match search?
If not could you please suggest an alternative approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have your `{"index": "not_analyzed"}` in the wrong location, it should be within the fields section. Try this mapping instead:

```
{
    doc: {
        "properties": {
            file : { 
                "type" : "attachment",
                "fields" : {
                    "title" : { "store" : "yes" },
                    "file" : {  "index" : "not_analyzed"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-attachment-type.html